# Laravel example project on PhpStorm is not compileable

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

I am very new to using Frameworks/Laravel and I haven't achieved to run the Laravel welcome website in PhpStorm yet.

**Steps I've done so far:**

1. I have created a new "Composer Project" with PhpStorm and chose Laravel as Package.
2. I installed the IDE helper in line with this tutorial: http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/01/laravel-development-using-phpstorm/
3. I installed XAMPP and started the Apache server on port 8000
4. Changed the PhpStorm Settings -> Language & Frameworks -> PHP -> Interpreter -> Path to php.exe inside of XAMPP
5. I tried to watch the results in a browser by clicking "Run". A PHP fatal error appeared in the debugger which said the class TestCase couldn't be found.
6. After googling I added the phpunit.xml as an alternative configuration file for my Run/Debug configurations. Furthermore I read that I need to add the "tests" folder inside of my project directory as "Directory Test Scope" there.
7. The debugger says "All Tests passed", but I am receiving a different fatal error which I wasn't able to solve until now:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method
>   PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult::deprecatedFeaturesCount() in
>   C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter.php on line 446
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException' with
>   message 'Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not
>   instantiable.' in C:\Users\kentor\PhpstormProjects\test
>   Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752
>   Stack trace:
>   0 C:\Users\kentor\PhpstormProjects\test Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(633):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Illuminate\Cont...', Array)
>   #1 C:\Users\kentor\PhpstormProjects\test Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\Cont...', Array)
>   #2 C:\Users\kentor\PhpstormProjects\test Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(154):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\Cont...')
>   #3 C:\Users\kentor\PhpstormProjects\test Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(79):
>   in C:\Users\kentor\PhpstormProjects\test
>   Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
>   on line 752 PHP
>   Fatal error:  Call to undefined method
>   PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult::deprecatedFeaturesCount() in
>   C:\xampp\php\pear\PHPUnit\TextUI\ResultPrinter.php on line 446 PHP
>   Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException' with
>   message 'Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler] is not
>   instantiable.' in C:\Users\kentor\PhpstormProjects\test
>   Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:752
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 C:\Users\kentor\PhpstormProjects\test Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(633):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->build('Illuminate\Cont...', Array)
>   #1 C:\Users\kentor\PhpstormProjects\test Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697):
>   Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\Cont...', Array)
>   #2 C:\Users\kentor\PhpstormProjects\test Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(154):
>   Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\Cont...')
>   #3 C:\Users\kentor\PhpstormProjects\test Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(79):
>   in C:\Users\kentor\PhpstormProjects\test
>   Laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php
>   on line 752
>
> Process finished with exit code 255

So in the end I want to see the contents of my "Public" folder.

**My questions:**

1. Why did I need to specify the "tests" folder? Is this used for verifying that PHP is compiling correctly or any similar testing stuff?
2. What did I miss in order to see my Laravel example page in the end?

Comment: So .. what do you actually want to do? Just execute/run your project (web site) .. or run your unit tests?

Comment: I only want to execute/run my project, I thought I was supposed to provide these settings.

Comment: Well .. you must be doing something completely wrong then ... as those errors suggest that you are trying to run PHPUnit tests (created wrong type of Run/Debug Configuration/). https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm